# Gnosis MultiSigWallet onlyWallet modifier

Tags: solidity, multisignature, gnosis

I was doing some research on the original [Gnosis MultiSigWallet contract](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol) and I was a bit confused by the onlyWallet modifier for adding, replacing, and removing owners. Since this function can only be called by the wallet how would the wallet call the functions on itself once deployed?

What I am thinking is that someone would have to submit a transaction with the wallet address as the destination and one of the onlyWallet functions encoded with args as data. Then when the transaction reached the required confirmations would the wallet then use the execute function to do an external call on itself, thus being able to add, remove, or replace an owner?